# Convert excel formula to VBA using function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a FormulaArray in excel which is

```
{=MAX(IF($DB$2:$DI$2<F10,$DB$2:$DI$2))}
```

and it worked perfectly. "F10" is equal 55, "then $DB$2:$DI$2" is a range of values between 41-102. Then i created a vba function and apply it in excel as a formula

```
=ClosestLessThan(F10,$DB$2:$DI$2)
```

but the result is #VALUE!", i cant figure out the right way. Here is what i have tried.

```
Function ClosestLessThan(searchNumber As Double, rangeOfValues As Range) As Double

Dim rng As Range

If rangeOfValues < searchNumber Then
Set rng = rangeOfValues
End If

ClosestLessThan = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

End Function
```

Comment: Any reason for not using native function?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij yes there is, for simplification. the formula will be shorter and i can select the range one time and avoiding ctrl+alt+enter key and errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your biggest issues is with this line:

```
If rangeOfValues < searchNumber Then
```

While the default for a `Range` object is `.Value`, VBA cannot interpret a `.Value` for a multi-cell `Range` object.

Another issue is the way you call it. In `=ClosestLessThan(F10,$DB$2:$DI$2)` `F10` is a cell reference (Range object), yet you assign that argument to a `double` data type.

Try this instead:

```
Function ClosestLessThan(searchNumber As Range, rangeOfValues As Range) As Double

Dim rng As Range

For each rng in rangeOfValues
     If rng < searchNumber.Value Then
         Dim rngSearch as Range
         If rngSearch is Nothing Then
            Set rngSearch = rng
         Else
            Set rngSearch = Union(rng, rngSearch)
         End If
     End If
Next

ClosestLessThan = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rngSearch)

End Function
```

And call as you do: `=ClosestLessThan(F10,$DB$2:$DI$2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it.

```
Function ClosestLessThan(dblRefVal As Double, rangeOfValues As Range) As Double
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In rangeOfValues
    If rng.Value < dblRefVal And rng.Value > ClosestLessThan Then ClosestLessThan = rng.Value
Next
End Function
```

The reason why your function is not working is because it is trying to compare complete range in one go and then use MAX function.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function ClosestLessThan(searchNumber As Double, rangeOfValues As Range) As Double

Dim min As Double

min = -1


For Each cell In rangeOfValues

   If cell.value < searchNumber And cell.value > min Then
     min = cell.value
   End If
  ' Debug.Print cell.value

Next cell

ClosestLessThan = min

End Function
```